# Django full_clean method and data security

Tags: django, django-models

I need to take raw JSON data and put it direct into a Django model by using the Mymodel.objects.create( ... ) method. If I then run full_clean() on the instance created, is it then secure in terms of potential SQL injection or any malicious data that could potentially be injected?

The reason that I am not using a form is that the logic on the form is quite complex in that it dynamically builds a form so I need to post data in json format. I don't want to use the rest api as there is just one page where it has this complexity.

Comment: Normally Django's ORM is secure against SQL injection, but you need to do a full clean *before*, since the Django ORM does *not* run a `full_clean`, and this validate data integrity.

Comment: That's great thanks, it sounds like it should be fine. Just needed the clarification as I wasn't sure if you had to run data through forms in order for it to be secure.

Comment: not secure in the sense that it performs SQL injection no, but that does not mean that the data is valid. Imagine that a person somehow makes a POST request such that he "likes" for example an object that he is not allowed to see by using its identifier, then later he might see the post because he managed to enter a record where he liked that object. SQL injection is not the only security threat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`.full_clean(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) does *not* perform any checks on SQL injection, nor does the Django ORM, since it simply *escapes* all parameters, so even if the data contains SQL statements, these are escaped, and therefore, normally, SQL injection is not possible.

But you need to run `full_clean` to validate *data integrity*. If you define constraints on your model, these are normally validated at the `full_clean` part. The ORM does *not* run these queries.

You thus can work with:

```
obj = Mymodel(**data)
obj.full_clean()
obj.save()
```

> The reason that I am not using a form is that the logic on the form is quite complex in that it dynamically builds a form.

A form can remove a lot of boilerplate code, since it does not only performs validation, but also *cleaning*, it makes error messages more convenient, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Django ORM protects the database from SQL-injections, but you are responsible for the output. For convenient data cleaning, I recommend using a [DRF Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)